# How do upload images remotely to Drupal using the Image module?

Tags: image, drupal, module

Images can be uploaded through Drupal's frontend interface with the Image module. However, I'd like to be able to upload and create image nodes remotely by requesting a URL and passing the image as a parameter. I have the REST API module, which works fine, but I can't figure out what function I need to call in the backend to create the image node. Does anyone know how to do this or if there's another module that does something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Gallerix module lets you turn on "Repository mode" that will make any images uplaoded to an FTP folder available to be included in its image galleries.  It would be a simple step from there using Drupal 6 triggers and actions to publish a node containing only that image.